# How to flow to a single tube (rather than a series)

Tags: python, twisted, glyph, tubes

It's possible that this is not an Issue at all and is instead my own misunderstanding of the underlying interface pattern.

Consider the following `tube`:

```
@tube
class Capitalizer:
    def received(self, value):
        yield value.upper()
```

...and then turning the flow on this way:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor, listenOn="unix:path=trying-tubes"):
    endpoint = clientFromString(reactor, listenOn)
    ipc_flow = yield flowFromEndpoint(endpoint)
    c = Capitalizer()
    ipc_flow.fount.flowTo(c)
    yield Deferred()
```

I get:
`builtins.AttributeError: 'Capitalizer' object has no attribute 'flowStopped'`

OK, so it seems like I haven't properly implemented the `tube` interface.

If I use it as a series:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor, listenOn="unix:path=trying-tubes"):
    endpoint = clientFromString(reactor, listenOn)
    ipc_flow = yield flowFromEndpoint(endpoint)
    c = Capitalizer()
    s = series(c)
    ipc_flow.fount.flowTo(s)
    yield Deferred()
```

...this works fine.

So, looking in `series()`, I see that it calls `IDrain` on my tube, which seems to outfit it with the drain and other necessary interfaces.

If I try to pass it to `IDrain` myself, I get:

`builtins.TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <__main__.Capitalizer object at 0x7fda958b8b70>, <InterfaceClass tubes.itube.IDrain>)`

This seems to be because the context manager inside `series`, which reads:

```
    with _registryActive(_tubeRegistry):
        ...
```

...makes the proper factory (that's `_tube2drain`) available in the context.

So, am I supposed to call some variant of `_tube2drain` myself if I want to just flow into (and out of) a single `tube`?